# Call jQuery function from AngularJS Controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a below button when on clicked shows a small popup like notification

```
<button id="element" type="button" onclick="ShowNotifications()" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Text inside popup">Notifications</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowNotifications() {
        $('#element').popover('open');
    }
</script>
```

My Intention is to Show this popup every few seconds without clicking the button, but from the AngularJS Controller.

```
 var showPop = function () {
    //how can i call that jQuery function here ??
    $timeout(showPop, 1000);
}
$timeout(showPop, 1000);
```

---

Tried with the below solution

```
app.directive("showNotifications", ["$interval", function ($interval) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {          
            $interval(function () {
                $(elem).popover("open");
                alert('hi');
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Also included the scripts

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>


<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/postsService.js"></script>   
<script src="js/directive.js"></script>

<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

using the directive like this

```
<button id="element" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Friend request 1" **show-notifications**>Live Notifications</button>
```

I see an error "the object has no method popover"

Comment: this type of stuff deserves a directive. Don't put ui logic in your controller. Also, no need for a recursive call, angular now supports `$interval`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Directives are used for DOM manipulation:

```
<button show-notifications>
```

And the directive

```
.directive("showNotifications", ["$interval", function($interval) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            //On click
            $(elem).click(function() {
                $(this).popover("open");
            });

            //On interval
            $interval(function() {
                $(elem).popover("open");
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I upvoted this, I will expand by saying that the body of `link` should call a `$interval(showPopup, 1000)`, which is really what the question is about.

Comment: @JoeMinichino -- Updated to show on click and interval

Comment: I tried the code and i see on error "The object has no method popover" If i put an alert i am able to see the alert.  I have also included all the scripts, i have modified the code, pls look above

Answer (score 17):

The following steps can be followed,

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
```

then create any regular angular module and controller and create a function inside the controller which we can use it for the calling any jquery function, e.g. I want to add a class to a div element.

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('hello',function($scope){
            $scope.name = 'Vikash';
            $scope.cities = ['Delhi','Bokaro','Bangalore'];

             $scope.hide = function(){
                jq('#hideme').addClass('hidden');   

            }
        });
```

and we will create some regular html to utilize that method with the controller.

```
<body ng-controller="hello">
    <div class="container" id="hideme">
        Hello Dear
    </div>
    <button ng-click="hide()">Hide Hello</button>
</body>
```

Now here you can see that we are about call addClass method from the jQuery inside the function declared in the controller and part of the $scpe.

Comment: This is great. You can also write out the `jQuery` instead of using `noConflict`, so it would look like this: `jQuery('#hideme').addClass('hidden');`

Answer (score 12):

Instead of a $ just place the key word angular

```
angular.element("#id").val()
```

Comment: i want to use something like this angular.element("#btn").click(function (event) {alert("hi");});  but jqLite does not support click method....what can be the other options.Please suggest.

Comment: There is no need to use JQuery for that use ng-click="yourFunction()" where yourFunction() is defined in the controller like <br/> $scope.yourFunction= function() {
        alert("hi");
    };