# jquery.submit function with angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

how we can submit form with angular controller?
another questions is how we can call jquery functions with angular?

```html
 <form id="flightRules" target="_blank" action="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/site/farerules" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="airlineCode" id="airlineCode" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="fareCode" id="fareCode" />
                        </form>
```

i have form in html and i want to submit that form with angular !(the same things that i did with jquery);

thanks!

Comment: Okay! go ahead do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer!

Add $element to controller. After that call $element.find("#yourformid").submit();.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like below:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" >
<form>
<input type="text" id="name" ng-model="myForm.name" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="12"> Name <br/>

<select ng-model="myForm.car">
  <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
  <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
</select>

<button ng-click="myForm.submitTheForm()">Submit Form</button>
</form>

<div>
    {{myForm.name}}
</div>
<div>
    {{myForm.car}}
</div>
```

```
<script>
 angular.module("myapp", [])
 .controller("MyController", function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.myForm = {};
   $scope.myForm.name = "Jakob Jenkov";
   $scope.myForm.car  = "nissan";

  $scope.myForm.submitTheForm = function(item, event) {
   console.log("--> Submitting form");
   var dataObject = {
      name : $scope.myForm.name
      ,car  : $scope.myForm.car
   };

   var responsePromise = $http.post("/angularjs-examples/json-test- data.jsp", dataObject, {});
   responsePromise.success(function(dataFromServer, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(dataFromServer.title);
   });
    responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("Submitting form failed!");
   });
 }

});
</script>
```

For Call Jquery Funtion with angular you can check with this link
[Call jQuery function from AngularJS Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714286/call-jquery-function-from-angularjs-controller)
Happy Coding :)

Comment: that is first question's answer. good. what about _another questions is how we can call jquery functions with angular?_.

Comment: sumbit form from angular controller like ( Jquery.form.submit() )something like that !     not the routine way of submitting form with angular

Comment: @mohsen `Jquery.form.submit()` here `.submit()` is js method not from jQuery.

Comment: doesn't matter i want this in angular

Answer (score -1):

ng-submit directive

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

to use jquery function you can create your own directive and apply your logic accordingly

[How to use jQuery in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666289/how-to-use-jquery-in-angularjs)

Comment: this might help     http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/forms.html#submitting-forms

Comment: problem solved!!!     add $element to controller after that call $element.find("#yourformid").submit();