# Using jQuery function inside AngularJS controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I needed to initialize a `jQuery` plugin on all elements with a certain class name which comes inside an `ng-repeat` loop. These elements are loaded via `angularjs` `$http get` method.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('get_item.php').success(function(response) {
        $scope.items = response;
        angular.element('.make-switch').bootstrapSwitch(); // jQuery plugin code
    });
});
```

But this doesn't work.
I tried `$('.make-switch').bootstrapSwitch();` also. Please help.

Comment: Create a custom directive, you should not do any plugin initialization in controller.

Comment: just use `$('.make-switch').bootstrapSwitch();` Provided you've included jQuery and this plugin script.

Comment: @AdityaParab OP is already doing it, can't you see? But there is a good reason why it won't work reliably. And that's the reason why it should not be part of controller responsibility.

Comment: There is a similiar post:
[Call jQuery function from AngularJS Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714286/call-jquery-function-from-angularjs-controller) I hope it helps you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a directive and so you can initialize the plugin in your markup:

```
<div bootstrapswitch></div>
```

I think you creates your elements dynamicly with the scope variable `$scope.items`, something like that:

```
<div class="make-switch" ng-repeat="item in items" bootstrapswitch></div>
```

...just add the attribute `bootstrapswitch` to initialize the switch on your loaded elements.

...your directive could look like that:

```
app.directive('bootstrapswitch', [function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
         $(elem).bootstrapSwitch();
      }
   };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you want to call any jQuery plugins inside angular code you can do this also with angular. It has built in jQuery called jqLite, and you can call this as `angular.element("selector")` which returns you a jQuery element. As a selector you can use any jQuery/css selectors you like.

By the way, calling jQuery directly in angular code like `$("selector").method()` is a bad practise. You should use only your angular jqLite functionallity

Comment: i used `angular.element('.make-switch').bootstrapSwitch();`

Comment: make sure your plugin included on webpage

Answer (score 1):

It not a pretty good idea to manipulate view using jQuery library inside Angular controller.
Actually jQuery is grabbing or injecting into your DOM based on events.But Angular doesn't act the same way, it manipulate view based on true/false nature.

Best alternative way is try to make directive or use [angular-bootstrap-switch](https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-bootstrap-switch) library.