# what is the best way to use jQuery plugin into Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using a jQuery plugin with Angular project but with the jQuery way like

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      //calling plugin here
    });
```

This is working fine. I know this is not the right way to do it and it's not highly recommended, but I have already searched a couple of blogs and websites on this topic. They said that we can create directive for this but I am not able to understand how I can create any directive for a jQuery plugin and how it will work? Is it possible to create an Angular directive for each jQuery plugin?

Comment: create any directive ????

Comment: refer this link: https://bencentra.com/code/2015/09/29/jquery-plugins-angular-directives.html

Answer (score 2):

You can create something like this

```
App.directive('jqueryPlugInDirective', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).[jqueryPlugin](ConfigOptions);
      }
    };
});
```

And your html will be something like

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="pluginLibFile.js"></script>    
 <div jquery-plug-in-directive></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not recomended to mix up jQuery and AngularJs but, Incase you just have to, You need to work with Angular's jqLite,

Here's the link for some reference - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: what is wrong if i go my way? as i shown in question.

Comment: I know this basic things. As you have printed hello, my goal is to call jQuery plugin inside this controller how can we call do you have any idea?

Comment: maybe this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515947/using-jquery-function-inside-angularjs-controller

Comment: I am glad @AniruddhaRaje mentioned this, there is no need for jQuery in Angular, it is not recommended to use jQuery with AngularJS and it is really a AngularJS best practice to NOT include jQuery, if you are manipulating the DOM Javascript is all you need

Comment: doesn't answer the question

Answer (score -1):

Well I prefer to use anonymous function passing passing global jQuery element.

```
(function($){
  //code 
})(jQuery);
```

Using anonymous function and passing jQuery as parameter eliminates the issues arising due to overriding of `$` by some other library.
As we are passing `(JQuery)` global object as parameter and receiving it into `($)`  so, $ is now with jQuery no matter if its overridden..

However, you can go with native Angular jQuery version .. `jQLite` also.. using `angular.Element()`.

You can read more about differences .. [jQuery document.ready vs self calling anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259496/jquery-document-ready-vs-self-calling-anonymous-function)

Comment: Thanks but again we are using jQuery how this way is different and good to my way?

Comment: @ArpitMeena your method has no issues untill we are using many libraries .. where some library may override `jQuery --- $` element ..  now passing jQuery global object solves the issue which may arise due to overriding of `$` .  You can see.. We are passing `(jQuery)` as parameter which is mapped as `($)` into the function .. and used inside the function.

Comment: @ArpitMeena one more thing to mention Angular provides its own jQuery extension `jQLite` you can always go with that without having any issue.. @Aniruddha Raje has already mentioned the same .

Comment: Thanks now i got the idea of directive.

Comment: This has nothing to do with using a plugin and doesn't answer the question