# Syntax highlighted code snippet wont display with AngularJs ngBind

Tags: angularjs, xml, syntax-highlighting

I used some Syntax highlighting API for highlighting code snippet for my web application.To do that i have used [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/) .I created popup model and inside model i have put `<pre>` tag and when model open it should display my highlighted `xml` string.

**HTML Code snippet**

```
<pre id="tepXml" ><code class="xml">{{tepXml}}</code></pre>
```

In AngularJs controller dynamically bind the value to `tepXml` from server.

**AngularJs controller**

```
...$promise.then(function(data){
    $scope.tepXml=data.xml;
}
```

But the problem was that when i open popup model my xml content is empty.nothing display anything.But when i removed `<code class="xml"></code>` from `<pre>` xml content would display with out highlighting.I referred some posts and used `$compile` in angularJs controller but the problem was still the same.

**AngularJs controller with $compile**

```
 var target = angular.element($window.document.querySelector('#tepXml'));
 var myHTML = data.xml;
 target.append( $compile( myHTML )($scope) );
```

If someone knows where i went wrong please point me out.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TIbKReWTu30KJzir9FtA?p=preview)

Comment: Are you calling the highlight api after the tepXml variable has been set?  Create a plunker to demo.

Comment: no i called it top of the page inside `<head>`

Comment: Create plunkr, might be simple problem, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is to do:

```
$promise.then(function(data){
  $scope.tepXml=data.xml;
  // Call highlight api
  $timeout(function() {
    $('pre#tepXml code').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);  //or whatever the correct highlightjs call is.
  });
});
```

The more Angular way of doing things is to call a jQuery function from Angular is to write a [Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714286/call-jquery-function-from-angularjs-controller).  Something like this:

```
.directive("highlightCode", function($interval) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: { highlightCode: "=" },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          $scope.$watch('highlightCode', function() {
            $(elem).find('code').each(function(i, block) {
            hljs.highlightBlock(block);  //or whatever the correct highlightjs call is.
          });
        }
    }
});
```

Used like this:

```
<pre id="tepXml" highlight-code="tepXml"><code class="xml">{{tepXml}}</code></pre>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but still the same.data wont bind.i checked using inspect and `<pre>` was empty.

Comment: i created a plunker and updated my post.i just simply put xml string and tested it.but its works fine.but when i put into my web app it wont highlight.I used inside `modal-dialog ` when button click model would visible and must show the content.but other attribute can see like xml file name etc...but cant see xml content its empty.

Comment: and i used some other CSS classes also for my other component could it be a problem?

Comment: Thanks for the Plunker - but since it's working it's going to be difficult to replicate.  Can you make the plunker show the problem or publish some github code that replicates to help.

Comment: thanks for the reply.but my web app is really a huge one so its really hard to create a plunker using peace of code from web app.